# DELETE FROM doesn't work in Python for SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I want to delete all rows in my tables that are empty. But the same command I use in SQL doesnt work in Python. Its on my raspberry and im using SQLite3.

**I dont get any error message doing:**

```
import sqlite3

currency_pairs = ['AUDUSD', 'EURCHF', 'EURUSD', 'EURCAD']

conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/ken/database/database.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

for c in currency_pairs:
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM {c} WHERE Close IS NULL;".format(c=c))

conn.close()
```

Again, using **DELETE FROM AUDUSD WHERE Close IS NULL;** for example works in my sqlite3 programm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `conn.commit()` when executing one or multiple delete statement(s). Committing is not necessary if you select.